# How to get return value from php to ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

-- Ajax Code

```
   var User = function(){
    return {
        init : function(){
            document.getElementById('login').addEventListener('click', this.login);
        },
        login : function(){
            var username = $("#username").val(),
                password = $("#password").val();

            $.ajax({
                url : 'http://localhost/oc2/user_info/login',
                method : 'post',
                dataType : 'json',
                data : {
                    username : username,
                    password : password
                },
                success : function(response){   
                    alert('h'); <-- add the php return value id here.
                    window.location.href = "main.html";
                },
                error : function(response){
                    alert(response.responseText);                   
                }
            });
        }
    };
}();
```

-- PHP CodeIgniter

```
public function login()
    {
        $post = $this->input->post();

        $where = array(
            'email_address' => $post['username'], //"turbobpo.johnrey@gmail.com", 
            'password' => md5($post['password']) //"e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e" 
        );

        $user_info = $this->get_by($where);



        if(isset($user_info['id']))
        {

            $this->session->set_userdata('user_info', $user_info);

            $response = array(
                'id' => $user_info['id'], <-- this i want to pass to my ajax
                'success' => TRUE
            );
        }
        else
        {
            $response = array(
                'success' => FALSE
            );
        }

        print json_encode($response);
    }
```

Hello can you help me for this part i already management to went far on this php ajax i'm not used in creating this application please i need help i place a comment on the codes to see where i wanna retrieve the value from php to my ajax code so i can use it on my next retrieving of file where i use the id of a login user to get his available access in a grid form. it would be a plus if you can also show me how can i use that data to pass it back in php again the id after retrieving it on the success ajax return array value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var User = function(){
    return {
        init : function(){
            document.getElementById('login').addEventListener('click', this.login);
        },
        login : function(){
            var username = $("#username").val(),
                password = $("#password").val();

            $.ajax({
                url : 'http://localhost/oc2/user_info/login',
                method : 'post',
                dataType : 'json',
                data : {
                    username : username,
                    password : password
                },
                success : function(response){   
                    response.id; // Here is the id JQuery parses JSON for you
                    window.location.href = "main.html";
                },
                error : function(response){
                    alert(response.responseText);                   
                }
            });
        }
    };
}();
```

Comment: sir how can i pass it back to php the response.id ?? or somehow like get that value in php code can you show me how?

Comment: You already got the id from the server why send it back? Anyway communication between client(javascript) and server(php) is one way from js to php, so js can do an ajax call then php returns result(JSON) and connection is over. If you need to send it back it's another ajax call

Comment: it was like a login system sir that when a user login id becomes the referrence for this access which is displayed to the main view in a grid. i see it now can i do it still on php pass it on a function which i call on the main view sorry i really am new here trying to understand this programming logic of the web thanks for the tips sir ..

Comment: Best to check the boolean variable `response.success` before trying to access `response.id` as it may be undefined in the case of a failure.

Comment: Glad to help, welcome to the community. If you are new to PHP don't jump to frameworks directly try to understand HTTP, request life cycle, GET, POST,.. frameworks hide those things making it hard to understand lower layers